# Laravel 5.6 Clicking activation link only redirect to homepage

Tags: php, laravel-5.6, laravel-passport

I am working on Laravel 5.6 of email activation and password forget. I successfully send the email after the registration or clicking the forgot password button after entering user's email. However, the website will redirect to the homepage(127.0.0.1:8000) instead of doing the activation or reset pw action once the user click on the activation link in email and its account is in logged in status.

An example here(email activation) :

Clicking a link(127.0.0.1:8000/register/activate/{sometokenhere}) inside the activation email will only going to the homepage itself(127.0.0.1:8000)

---

Inside the RegisterController.php,

```
...
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name'     => $data['name'],
        'email'    => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'activate'   => 0,
        'activation_token' => str_random(60),   
    ]);
    $user->notify(new SignupActivate($user));   
    return $user;
}

public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
    $this->guard()->login($this->create($request->all()));
    return redirect()->to($this->redirectTo); //homepage
}

public function signupActivate($token)
{
    $user = User::where('activation_token', $token)->first();
    if (!$user) {
        return response()->json([
            'user' => $user,
            'token' => $token,
            'message' => 'This activation token is invalid.'
        ], 404);
    }
    $user->active = 1;
    $user->activation_token = '';
    $user->save();
    return $user;
}
...
```

Inside the Notification/SignupActivate.php,

```
...
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['mail'];
}

public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    $url = url('/register/activate/'.$notifiable->activation_token);

    $name = $this->user->name;
    $email = $this->user->email;
    return Mail::send('activate', ['name'=>$name, 'url'=>$url], function($message) use($email, $name){
    $message->to($email, $name)
        ->from('test@test.com', 'Admin')
        ->subject('Activate your account');            
    });
}
...
```

related route,

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/register/activate/{token}', 'RegisterController@signupActivate'); //added
 });
```

activate.blade.php,

```
Hi {{$name}},<br><br>
This email is a confirmation email.<br>
<a href={{$url}} data-method="delete">Activation link</a>
```

Comment: I'm so new in Laravel. I wonder it's routing problem, session problem(?) or somthing else. I am not sure I explain my situation clear enough or not.. I can activate the account only if the user account is logged out(result of clicking the activatoin link will return json string back to the screen).

Comment: I just comment the line like this inside the RedirectAuthenticated.php: 
if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            // return redirect('/');
} It seem work fine, but any risk to do it in this way?